# SPD Data Sources Not Visible between Users

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Has anyone seen this or can explain why other user's do not see the Data Sources created by different users ?

A remote colleague opens a site in SP Designer and makes a Soap Data Source connection.  When I open the very same site I do not see his newly created Data Source!?

Furthermore, if I create a Soap Data Source and give it the same name as his SPD complains that it cannot save.  I assume it knows one exists already with the same name but does not display it.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply a big lack of pertinent information, so it is a wild guessing game:

- [Loopback Security Check](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)
- double hop authentication problems
- firewal settings
- Is SOAP sevice requires authentication and, if not, whether anonymous access is permitted in your environment
- configuration of proxies
- etc.